# Blackberry 4.2.0 - How can I tell which RIM APIs require the location permission?

Tags: blackberry, permissions

It looks like BlackBerry OS works out the permissions required by an application by inspecting the APIs it links to.

I've been tasked with removing the request for the location permission from an existing application, so that users are never prompted to allow it. Unfortunately, I think this means I need to hunt down and remove any imports to the location-requiring APIs.

The problem is: I can't find any documentation that says "API x requires 'y' and 'z'".

Does it exist?
Are there any non-obvious APIs that require it?
I have removed GPS and RadioInfo, to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse for your BlackBerry development, then go to Window->Preferences->BlackBerry Java Plug-In->Warnings and switch on code signing warnings for (I think, in your instance) RIM BlackBerry Apps API.

This will at least highlight the lines in your code (with a yellow triangle) which will require code signing, and they will also appear in your Problems View.

Comment: Ha, the first thing I did with the blackberry plugin was turn off those entirely useless warnings! Anyway, thanks - that's a good idea and probably the best solution to this problem. The actual solution to my issue wasn't quite as straightforward: it turns out I _had_ successfully removed all requirements for that permission, but triggering a permission prompt caused the device to list all permissions configured to the default of 'Allow', which is what was throwing me off.